# How to fix "cordova build ios error code 70"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build

*cordova build ios* generates the error below

**Tried:**

*cordova platform remove ios*

*cordova platform add ios*

*cordova prepare ios*: Gives me same error

**Cordova-Plugins:**

cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"

cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"

cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"

phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"

phonegap-plugin-push 1.9.1 "PushPlugin"

**cordova version:** 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

**Xcode version:** 9.1 (9B55)

```
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/seblon/ssdalarm/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,SSD-Alarm.xcworkspace,-scheme,SSD-Alarm,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/seblon/ssdalarm/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/seblon/ssdalarm/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch'
    at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by myself:

*cordova build ios --device*